# Comment explique-t-on le sens de « ver » dans la locution « Tirer les vers du nez » ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, origine-ou-raison, comparaison-de-langues

On a l'expression (lui) *tirer les [vers](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ver#Fran%C3%A7ais) du [nez](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_les_vers_du_nez)* pour « obtenir de quelqu'un, par la parole, une information qu'il ne souhaite pas donner » ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nez)), par exemple :

> Ils tentaient de lui tirer les vers du nez.
>  ⁠— Nous, on ne
>   demande qu'à travailler avec vous... Ni Boivert ni moi ne connaissons
>   la ville... Enfin... Bref...
>   Devant le mutisme de Maigret,
>   l'homme ne savait plus que dire.
>  — Ce sera comme vous voudrez,
>   quoi!... Mais sûrement que ces messieurs du Parquet savent que vous
>   êtes ici...
>
> [ Georges Simenon, extrait de *Les vacances de Maigret* (1948), au
>   TLFi « [nez](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nez) » ]

Au *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française* (sup. A. Rey, chez *Robert*, 2011) on en dit ceci :

> [La locution] (1405) reste mal expliquée ; on ne peut identifier ces
>   vers aux parasites du nez qu'avaient cru découvrir les Encyclopédistes
>   du 18<sup>e</sup> (*vers rinaires, nasicoles*) ni aux comédons comme
>   le faisait [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/nez) ; on a suggéré que *ver* serait ici un doublet
>   ancien de *vrai* mais la même métaphore existe en anglais, avec *to
>   worm a secret out of somebody* « faire parler qqn. » (de *worm* « ver de
>   terre »). Le ver pourrait représenter ici un élément secret, caché,
>   interne et peu avouable.

Peut-on mieux l'expliquer aujourd'hui soit en identifiant :

- Que les locutions en langue française et en langue anglaise sont de faux amis et en détaillant le doublet ancien pour *vrai* ?
- Qu'il s'agit d'un calque ou d'un emprunt à l'anglais et en réconciliant le *ver de terre* avec le *nez* ?
- Le sens de *ver* pour l'« élément secret, caché, interne et peu avouable » antérieur à 1405 ?

Ou autrement ?

Comment: J’ignore les origines de ces locutions mais pour moi il s’agit maintenant de deux métaphores distinctes.  La locution *to worm something out of someone* fait allusion principalement au procédé lent mais tout de à fait implacable qui permet de faire sortir les renseignements, et même si on comprend aussi que ce procédé opère dans le noir, sur des informations en quelque sorte « enterrées », ce ne sont pas les informations elles-mêmes qu’on met en rapport avec des vers. En plus, il n’est pas question de faire sortir quoi que ce soit du nez de l’interrogé, encore moins des vers de t. visqueux...

Comment: S’agissant de « nez », si l’on veut assimilé un secret à un ver, il faut prendre en compte le fait que, en principe, si on a la malheur d’être infesté par des vers, on veut bien qu’on nous les extrait :-0. Il faut donc ajouter un élément pour faire comprendre que ce procédé n’est pas du tout bienveillant  - en l’occurrence, le fait qu’on les extrait par le nez.

Comment: OED : ***to worm a person in the nose***: *to extract information from him by adroit questioning. Obs. Cf. F. tirer à quelqu’un les vers du nez.* Avec un exemple daté de 1613, donc postérieur aux premiers emplois trouvés en français. L'emploi de *worm out* seul pour signifier *to extract (information, a secret, etc.) by insidious questioning.* semble plus récent encore d'après les exemples donnés (1745 pour le plus ancien). Donc on peut subodorer que l'emprunt s'est fait du français vers l'anglais.

Comment: Si le DHLF date de 1677 « le ver de la conscience », l'OED fait remonter l'emploi figuré de *worm* (nom) pour désigner *a grief or passion that preys stealthily on a man’s heart or torments his conscience (like a worm in a dead body or a maggot in food)* au X siècle. Peut-être que cet emploi est aussi plus ancien en français et je pencherais pour l'instant pour l'« élément secret, caché, interne et peu avouable. »

Comment: @Laure Fort intéressant et pourrait faire l'objet d'une réponse qui sans expliquer parfaitement restreindrait la solution à un des scénarios où en éliminerait d'autres. Je n'ai malheusemeent pas accès au OED. En lisant le DHLF je me suis demandé si 1677 aurait pu être antérieur mais ce qu'on tente de soutirer à qqn. ne lui donne pas de remords nécessairement donc je n'ai pas mentionné le ver de conscience ; par ailleurs si c'est les caractéristiques du ver de terre qui font l'expression, pourquoi référer au nez alors alors, pourquoi ne pas avoir fait comme en anglais. C'est intrigant.

Comment: @Minty Je ne vois pas exactement pourquoi viser le nez serait plus ou moins bienveillant que les oreilles ou les yeux. La référence chirurgicale ou interne, aux entrailles, de l'estomac, de sous la peau, des os etc., aurait pu être plus forte/troublante. Je ne suis pas convaincu, mais c'est possible.

Comment: Puisque les vers n’infestent pas le nez, enfin pas à ce que je sache, j’avais compris « lui extraire des vers par le nez », pour lui causer un max de gêne – mais j’ai peut-être tort. En tout cas, l’hypothèse de @Laure (1er commentaire) me semble tout à fait vraisemblable. Il y aurait donc eu un changement de sens en anglais, tandis que la locution française est restée inchangée.

Comment: Je n'ai pas fait de réponse parce que je n'émets que des suppositions et je n'ai pas vraiment d'éléments de réponse, j'avais plutôt l'impression de prolonger ta question ! Je vais y réfléchir et mûrir tout ça.

Answer (score 2):

Autre explication plus que plausible, mais qui n'est donné nulle part ailleurs:
Si on pense "vers" dans le sens "phrase" ou "mots" ou "assemblage de mots" ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vers/81638?q=vers#80672)), "tirer les vers du nez" voudrait dire tirer les mots - la vérité - par le nez, parce que la bouche est fermée - autrement dit, quand la personne ne veut rien dire !

Comment: On peut alors s'attendre à des rimes nasales...

Comment: ...ou à parler du nez. Au TLFi on a _ne pas tirer un mot de qqn (qui ne veut pas répondre)_ dans une autre catégorie sémantique que celle où l'on a classé la locution avec le nez. C'est que je me demandais si la composante verbale était vraiment associée à la parole. Par exemple je connais _cracher le morceau_. Est-ce que c'est forcer quelqu'un à faire quelque chose ou c'est obtenir par adresse. Je trouve ça intéressant. Malheuseusement A. Rey n'aura pas la chance de venir nous répondre un jour...

Answer (score 1):

On peut faire observer que le *Grand Robert de la langue française* associait *vers* dans *tirer les vers du nez* aux vers rinaires et faisait remonter la locution au 17e siècle en renvoyant au *Dandin* de Molière.

Du *Grand Robert* au *Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, la copie a été revue.  L'expression est datée dans le DHLF de 1405.  Il aurait été utile d'en dire un peu plus sur ses premières attestations.

Le *Dictionnaire des locutions en moyen français*, l'admirable dictionnaire de Giuseppe Di Stefano, donne cinq exemples d'emploi de *tirer les vers du nez*, quatre d'entre eux sont dus à Christine de Pizan (1364 - vers 1430), le cinquième de Jacques Grévin est bien postérieur et remonte à 1561.

On peut se demander d'ailleurs si ce n'est pas Christine qui a introduit l'expression en français.  Elle était venue en France à l'âge de quatre ans à la suite de son père, Tommaso di Benvenuto da Pizzano, médecin et astrologue de renom, diplômé de l'université de Bologne où il enseignait, qu'avait fait venir à sa cour Charles V.  Thomas de Pizan avait particulièrement soigné l'éducation de sa fille qui accédait librement à la bibliothèque du Roi et il n'est pas impossible qu'il lui ait fait acquérir des connaissances en médecine, ce qui permettrait de conjecturer une explication médicale et nous ramènerait aux vers rinaires.

Je verse également au dossier une partie de l'article *tanne*, c'est-à-dire *point noir* de l'Encyclopédie de Diderot et d'Alembert (http://enccre.academie-sciences.fr/encyclopedie/article/v15-2943-0/) :

> TANNE, s. f. (Physiolog.)​​ Les tannes sont l’humeur sébacée de la sueur & de la transpiration retenue dans ses petits canaux excrétoires.
>
> La portion qui couvre le bout du nez, des aîles du nez & du menton, &c. est chargée d’un grand nombre de follicules sébacées qui produisent une secrétion d’un liquide huileux, lequel demeure arrêté dans les petits canaux excrétoires par une transpiration retenue, à cause du défaut de chaleur qui la rend moins abondante dans cette partie. Cette humeur arrêtée s’épaissit & se durcit dans les follicules, d’où on la fait sortir en forme de petits **vers** par l’expression, & avec une épingle.
>
> Les tannes ne sont donc autre chose qu’une humeur blanchâtre, huileuse & terreuse de la sueur retenue dans les follicules sébacées du menton, du bout du nez, qui forme comme des mailles, tandis que la matiere qui leur servoit de véhicule s’évapore par la chaleur & la transpiration. Cette matiere remplit peu-à-peu ces follicules ou mailles ; alors il en regorge une partie par les petits trous excrétoires qui sont sur la peau.
>
> Comme cette matiere est tenace & gluante, elle retient la crasse & la poudre qui vole sur le visage ; & quoiqu’on l’essuie souvent, non-seulement on n’emporte pas la crasse qui s’est placée sur les extrémités des tannes qui sont dans les enfoncemens de ces trous ; mais au contraire le linge qui essuie le visage, la ramasse & la presse dans ces creux, où elle reste & produit ces petits points noirs, qui paroissent dans les pores de presque tous les nez, & qui forme le petit bout noir de la tanne quand on la fait sortir de son trou, en la pinçant d’une certaine façon.
>
> Voilà ce qui persuade les personnes peu instruites, que les tannes sont des **vers** qui s’engendrent dans la peau, & que ce petit point en est la tête, au lieu que c’est un petit peloton de l’humeur sébacée & ​​dessechée dans les réseaux de la peau, dont la petite extrémité qui regarde le jour, est sale & crasseuse par la poudre qui sans cesse vole dessus, & en est retenue par la matiere gluante de la tanne même. Il doit paroître plus de tannes sur le nez & sur le menton qu’aux autres endroits du visage, à cause de leur plus grand nombre de follicules sébacées.
>
> C’est donc sans fondement qu’on a pris les tannes pour des **vers**, mais je crois plus, c’est que très souvent on s’est trompé, quand on a cru, par des incisions, avoir **tiré des vers du nez**, des sourcils & des différentes parties du visage. En effet, sans vouloir nier qu’effectivement il se trouve quelquefois des **vers** dans le nez, dans les sourcils & dans d’autres parties extérieures du corps humain, il est constant qu’on se fait très-souvent illusion sur cet article, & que ce que l’on prend pour des **vers**, n’est communément que du pus épaissi. Lorsqu’un bouton a suppuré sans qu’on en ait fait sortir la matiere, elle s’y fige, & devient de la consistance d’une pâte. Le bouton reste ouvert, & le pus qui le remplit paroît sur cette ouverture comme une tache brune, parce que l’air en a séché & durci le dessus ; c’est cette tache que l’on prend pour la tête d’un **ver**, il faut le faire sortir. On presse le bouton ; le pus en sortant par l’ouverture du bouton, prend une forme cylindrique, c’est le **ver** qui sort la tête la premiere. La pression n’étant pas de tous côtés égale, ce pus ne sort pas par-tout en égale quantité, cela fait qu’il se recoquille en divers sens, & voilà le **ver** qui sort vivant, & qui fait des contorsions. En faut-il davantage pour établir une opinion populaire ? On n’auroit cependant qu’à toucher ce prétendu **ver**, pour se convaincre qu’il n’étoit rien moins que ce qu’on le croyoit, & c’est ce dont on ne s’avise pas.

*Voilà ce qui persuade les personnes peu instruites*, *opinion populaire* peut-on lire, ne peut-on pas conclure de cet article que les points noirs étaient communément appelés des vers et qu'on peut rejoindre Littré?

Il serait quoi qu'il en soit intéressant de savoir pourquoi le DHLF rejette les explications de prime abord convaincantes avancées par Littré, les  encyclopédistes et le Grand Robert.

Comment: C'est intéressant de comprendre pourquoi on pouvait voir dans ces manipulations de la peau l'action de « tirer des vers » mais je ne vois pas en quoi ça expliquerait qu'on ait choisi ça pour signifier _obtenir une information de quelqu'un en le questionnant_. Et pourquoi on n'aurait pas utilisé _tirer les vers de la peau_  ou _du visage_ plutôt que du _nez_. Il serait bien en effet que le DHLF explique pourquoi on ne retient pas cette explication...

Answer (score 0):

Google vous fournit de multiples explications, dont l'une est qu'au quinzième siècle (et avant) de nombreuses personnes étaient affectées par des parasites dans la cavité nasale et que cette maladie, quelque peu honteuse, nécessitait un interrogatoire serré de la Faculté pour parvenir au diagnostic.

Pour ma part, bien que cette explication puisse paraître convaincante, je pense que la fortune contemporaine de cette expression est plus triviale : tout le monde a pratiqué le "nose-picking", de préférence dans un lieu privé, et tout le monde sait que c'est une activité assez peu digne, mais finalement de peu de conséquence si vous n'infligez pas ce malheureux spectacle à des tiers. Lorsqu'on vous dit "On va te tirer les vers du nez, "bastard"", cela signifie qu'on va s'introduire dans ta sphère privée et pratiquer du "nose-picking" dans ton nez avec des doigts qui ne sont pas les tiens. C'est évidemment horrible, obscène, mais je pense que c'est cette image invasive dans une partie intime de votre corps qui continue à frapper les esprits à l'époque contemporaine.

Comment: La première interprétation des _vers rinaires_ est rejetée par le DHLF. Mais donc ça impliquerait que la locution en anglais n'est pas reliée comme il s'agit du ver de terre... On semble avoir une locution similaire alors qu'en anglais on n'aurait pas eu besoin de l'anatomie. Je ne suis pas certain qu'au 15e on avait les mêmes sensibilités. Je ne suis pas convaincu mais c'est une interprétation possible.